# Catch-22: mongo can't repair database because there isn't enough disk space?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I am restoring a Mongo database from a dumpfile and having problems. I cannot repair the database because there isn't enough free space, and now I'm stuck.

So I imported 10 million rows, and now I want to create an index on the collection. But when I try to create the index, Mongo errors - there isn't enough free memory.

So I decided to delete half the rows and then reclaim the free space:

```
> for (var v = db.page_statistics.find().sort({_id:1}).limit(5000000);v.hasNext();) { 
    db.page_statistics.remove(v.next()); 
}
> db.govuk_info_page_statistics.count();
5828632 # this worked, only 5 milion rows left
```

Next I tried to run a database repair to reclaim the free space:

```
> db.repairDatabase();
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Cannot repair database backdrop having size: 19268632576 (bytes) because free disk space is: 9958019072 (bytes)"
}
```

What can I do? I can't reclaim enough disk space to create the index without running a database repair, but I also haven't got enough disk space to run the repair, so I'm stuck in a catch-22.

Answer (score 3):

In order to repair database you should have disk space double than your existing database.
In repair database operation mongodb repairs the data file and keeps the repaired file in another location i.e it creates copy of existing data file. So without enough disk space you cannot repair database.

Answer (score 3):

If possible, you can create a replica set, and the replicating members will have the free space reclaimed.

You can then step down with your primary, stop mongod, and delete the data files.

When starting mongod again, this server will replicate the data from the new server, and have smaller file size (or at least as small as possible considering your data).